# How do I redirect my Active Directory users from google.com to my web service?

Tags: windows, powershell, dns, active-directory, redirect

I'm setting up a windows server 2012 R2 environment, and want to redirect my users to a web service. Meaning, I want to redirect www.google.com to let's say 127.0.0.1 (localhost) where I have my own google page.
Preferably, doing it with Powershell

This is for learning purposes of using honey-pots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer, search in DNS Manager for the folder Conditional Forwarders and right-click "New Conditional Forwarder".
Enter the name and ip and select the dns range :)